# Return the first option of select

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i had the below code,

```
<select id="my_select">
<option id=1>Option 1</option>
<option id=2>Option 2</option>
<option id=3>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

How would I return the first option id when the page loads, not when its selected. I've tried such things as  onLoadId = $('#my_select option).attr('id') under the jquery on load function, but that's not working.

Comment: Tip: id should start with an alphabet

Comment: @MehulMohan not required...can start with number

Comment: @charlietfl Oh yes. HTML5 loosens the restrictions. Thanks for informing!

Comment: @bazithedeveloper, it is working for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes it did... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `eq()` method, which reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```js
var x=$('#my_select option:eq(0)').attr('id');
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select">
<option id=1>Option 1</option>
<option id=2>Option 2</option>
<option id=3>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Another way is to use `first()` method.

See reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/first/).

```js
var x=$('#my_select option').first().attr('id');
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select">
<option id=1>Option 1</option>
<option id=2>Option 2</option>
<option id=3>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
   $('#my_select option:eq(0)').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Numerous ways to create the selector

```
 $('#my_select option:eq(0)')
 $('#my_select option').eq(0)
 $('#my_select option:first')
 $('#my_select option').first()
 $('#my_select option:nth-child(1)')
 $('#my_select option:first-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "option#1"

```
$("#my_select option#1").attr('id')
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add some description to your answer? It'll be much more valuable for other users then. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer